# VisualStudio 2017 mouse select area with ALT key not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, editor

Since VS2013 there is a feature in editor to select an "rectangle area" (column) of code not following lines by pressing ALT key + mouse selection.

I just upgraded to VS2017 and this does not work.
I cannot find it in options nor do I know what it is called.

I have the MS productivity tool installed.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am in VS2017 and it's working. Are you dragging your mouse? Are you having those options as they seem to be responsible for the functionality? (it works for both '*Shift + Alt*' and '*Alt*' for me).

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse click or

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse drag

The relative options seems to be 'Edit.LineUpExtendColumn' and 'Edit.LineEndExtendColumn'.

[image: screenshot of visual studio options window at 'environment - keyboard' section]

Comment: It is working now after a full restart Visual Studio.many thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me even after restarting VS. Go figure.

Comment: Try disabling plugins for a possible conflict. @Marc.2377

Comment: I did, no success. But just made it work by first clicking and ***then*** pressing (hold) the Alt key. Weird, huh?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for Visual Studio 2017, I had to **first click/drag, and *then* press and hold the
<kbd>Alt</kbd> key**. Otherwise it never works at all.